# jquery target class inside of parent sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, target

I have HTML like this

```
<div class="wsdRow">
    <div class="ib swsLbl">(new)</div>
    <div class="ib swsLbl">
        <input type="text" class="wsd">
    </div>
    <div class="ib swsLbl">
        <input type="text" class="wsAmount numbersOnly">
    </div>
    <div class="ib swsLbl">
        <button class="saveWC">save</button>
        <button class="delWC">-</button>
        <div class="wcResult ib"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

Then I bind the 'saveWC' button like this with a test function

```
        $(".saveWC").click(function(){          
            var thisDesc= $(this).parent().siblings().find(".wsd").val();

            console.log(thisDesc);

        });
```

What I want is to target the wsd class which is a child of the button's parent's sibling but I keep getting "undefined".

Comment: Works perfectly fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6pey1xcd/**

Comment: dang that makes it harder.... something else I'm doing wrong apparently

Comment: If you're getting `undefined`, at least the event handler is working. Now all you have to do is log the parent element, then the siblings, then the found elements etc. until you find where it no longer finds what is expected, and then debug from there

Comment: I'm adding these rows dynamically and somehow something was getting unbound.  Stepping it through showed me the bug. thanks